# How to Fetch data of specific Item only from array in react native

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native

My data is Look Like this

This is sub category list :

```
{
    "statusCode": 200,
    "status": "SUCCESS",
    "responseContents": [
        {
            "webimage": [],
            "appimage": [],
            "_id": "6155c2c77f31f9b79ba4273b",
            "Categories": "Tools & Machineries",
            "Subcategories": [
                "Power & Hand Tools ",
                "Plant Cutting tools",
                "All Tools & Home Improvement",
                "Tool Storage & Organization",
                "Tool Organisers",
                "Pneumatic Tools",
                "Carbide Cutting Tools",
                "Tool Storage & Organization",
                "Tools & Workshop Equipment",
                "TOOLS & EQUIPMENTS",
                "Hand Tools"
            ]
        },
        {
            "webimage": [],
            "appimage": [],
            "_id": "6155c2c77f31f9b79ba4273c",
            "Categories": "Furniture",
            "Subcategories": [
                "Wooden Furniture",
                "Office Furniture",
                "Kitchen Furniture",
                "Modular Office Furniture",
                "Industrial Furniture",
                "Steel Furniture",
                "Living Room Furniture",
                "|Storage and Display Furniture",
                "Entryway Furniture",
                "Inflatable Furniture",
                "Patio Furniture & Accessories",
                "Storage and Display Furniture",
                " Office & Commercial Furniture "
            ]
        },
        {
            "webimage": [],
            "appimage": [],
            "_id": "6155c2c77f31f9b79ba4273d",
            "Categories": "Safety & Security",
            "Subcategories": [
                "Industrial Safety Equipments",
                "Safety Equipment",
                "Fire Fighting Equipments",
                "Traffic Safety Equipment",
                "Marine Safety Equipment",
                "Welding Safety Accessories",
                "Work Safety Equipment & Gear",
                "PERSONAL PROTECTION EQUIPMENTS",
                "General Safety Equipment ",
                " Fire Fighting & Prevention Products ",
                "SAFETY MATERIALS (PPE)"
            ]
        },
        {
            "webimage": [],
            "appimage": [],
            "_id": "6155c2c77f31f9b79ba4273e",
            "Categories": "Lighting",
            "Subcategories": [
                "LED COMMERCIAL LIGHTING",
                "Panel Light",
                "Ceiling Lights",
                "Indoor Lighting ",
                "Flood Lights",
                "Lighting Fixtures ",
                "Lights & Fittings",
                " Indoor Lights & Lighting Accessories"
            ]
        }
        ...
    ]
}
```

Now I want to Fetch Data of a specific Category Only. For Example, I want to fetch Data OF Tools & Machineries Category Only. How can I do that please help

Comment: This isn't a code-writing service. Show what you've tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const data = {"statusCode":200,"status":"SUCCESS","responseContents":[{"webimage":[],"appimage":[],"_id":"6155c2c77f31f9b79ba4273b","Categories":"Tools & Machineries","Subcategories":["Power & Hand Tools ","Plant Cutting tools","All Tools & Home Improvement","Tool Storage & Organization","Tool Organisers","Pneumatic Tools","Carbide Cutting Tools","Tool Storage & Organization","Tools & Workshop Equipment","TOOLS & EQUIPMENTS","Hand Tools"]},{"webimage":[],"appimage":[],"_id":"6155c2c77f31f9b79ba4273c","Categories":"Furniture","Subcategories":["Wooden Furniture","Office Furniture","Kitchen Furniture","Modular Office Furniture","Industrial Furniture","Steel Furniture","Living Room Furniture","|Storage and Display Furniture","Entryway Furniture","Inflatable Furniture","Patio Furniture & Accessories","Storage and Display Furniture"," Office & Commercial Furniture "]},{"webimage":[],"appimage":[],"_id":"6155c2c77f31f9b79ba4273d","Categories":"Safety & Security","Subcategories":["Industrial Safety Equipments","Safety Equipment","Fire Fighting Equipments","Traffic Safety Equipment","Marine Safety Equipment","Welding Safety Accessories","Work Safety Equipment & Gear","PERSONAL PROTECTION EQUIPMENTS","General Safety Equipment "," Fire Fighting & Prevention Products ","SAFETY MATERIALS (PPE)"]},{"webimage":[],"appimage":[],"_id":"6155c2c77f31f9b79ba4273e","Categories":"Lighting","Subcategories":["LED COMMERCIAL LIGHTING","Panel Light","Ceiling Lights","Indoor Lighting ","Flood Lights","Lighting Fixtures ","Lights & Fittings"," Indoor Lights & Lighting Accessories"]}]};

function getBySubCategory(dataSet, category){
  return dataSet.find(o => o.Categories===category);
}

const dataSet = data.responseContents;
console.log(getBySubCategory(dataSet, 'Tools & Machineries'));
console.log(getBySubCategory(dataSet, 'Safety & Security'));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0 }
```

Comment: thanks but undefined is coming. What is use of that === category

Comment: Its for matching list `Category` with search category, you will get undefined when you will enter invalid `Category` key. Try running above example

Comment: If I defined data like above then its work fine but when I set my API response it It Then its giving undefined - My state is like this =  const [CategoryForSub, setCategoryForSub] = useState('');,  and I am setting like this -  setCategoryForSub(response);

Comment: are you including this line `const dataSet = serverResponseData.responseContents;`, You can share your code where you are adding above code.

Comment: Thank Bro Thank You so much .. You Did it. And Thank You too @Ouroborus. Indians Are always there for me ..